# Can I compare Cohen's and Fleiss' kappa values?

Tags: agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

I am running an experiment where a number of human specialists perform a task by hand, and then a computer algorithm performs the same task. I want to determine how similar the algorithm's results are to those of the humans. To do this, I am calculating Fleiss' kappa amongst the human specialists to obtain a measure of how much they agree with each other; the value is 0.6273.

Then I am comparing the algorithm's results to each of the individual specialists by using Cohen's kappa, thus obtaining a value for each specialist such as 0.7105 or 0.6881, to determine how much the algorithm disagrees with each particular specialist. If I can compare Cohen's and Fleiss' kappa values, my results seem to indicate that the algorithm does not disagree with any of the individual specialists more than specialists amongst themselves, which is a nice result.

However, I am not sure that comparing Cohen's and Fleiss' kappa values makes sense.